# Can a 2d matrix have a 1d vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider a matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$

it has eigenvector

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

Even though the system is 2 dimensional its vector space is 1 dimensional. I am a physicist and was trying to understand this

Comment: What do you mean by "its vector space"? If you mean the space of eigenvectors, you may want to look up generalised eigenvectors and the Jordan Normal Form.

Comment: So in QM given a Hamiltonian in matrix form it has eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The eigenvectors are said to form basis of the vector space of the given hamiltonian.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ has characteristic equation given by $\lambda^{2}=0$ so the eigenvalue is given by $\lambda=0$ with algebraic multiplicity $2$. By other hand the eigenspace is given by ${\rm span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$. Hence the geometric multiplicity is $1$. We have that algebraic multiplicy is not equal to geometric multiplicity, hence the matrix $ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is not diagonalizable in that sense. **But** we can considerate the generalised eigenvectors and then we can find the Jordan descomposition
$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}$.Hence in the Jordan sense the square matrix is diagonalizable. I am not a physicist, but in mathematics this means that in Jordan's sense it is possible to sum the generalized eigenspaces to create the corresponding Jordan diagonal matrix. That is "the matrix is not defective".

Comment: Thanks then does it mean that generalized eigenvector and the eigenvector form a vector space of the given matrix ? As far as I know the matrix acting on the generalized eigenvector does not give us the eigenvalue equation.